# How detect API breaks in C++

Tags: c++, static-analysis

How can I detect incompatible API changes in C++? **(not ABI but API changes)**

Where compatible changes are things that can't break compilation of code using the API like:

- parameter(s) added to method with default argument
- methods added to a class
- members added to a class
- classes added
- order of members or methods changed
- comments/documentation changes

And incompatible changes are things that potentially break compilation of code using the API like:

- removed arguments, (public/protected) methods, members, classes
- type changes of arguments or members
- name changes of public/protected members or methods
- classes moved from one header to another

Comment: Even if it made sense, this is off-topic as it's asking for recommendations. Why is someone with a rep of 2000 asking this?

Comment: Point taken. Your counter-question is off-topic! ;-)

Comment: Use a dummy project that uses all the features from the API and see if anything breaks when compiling that with the new library. Kind of unit testing (which should be done additionally) just on a different level. Though depending on the extent if that API writing such a dummy project isn't going to be fun.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking at a quite large API with hundreds of classes. I was hoping for something more automatic involving C++ parsing...

Comment: @user3791372: Recommendations are perfectly fine, as long as they're not **resource** recommendations. Methodology recommendations are fully on-topic.

Comment: The assumed "safe"  changes are in fact not safe. Adding a `virtual` method breaks an ABI, as does reordering them. Changing the signature of a base class method break derived classes that overrode that method. Adding a defaulted argument generally breaks an  ABI (since the default value is inserted at the call site). Classes added in a namespace may hide other classes from another namespace. Of the listed changes, only "comments" are safe. That one is luckily trivial to check: remove all comments and compare the stripped results.

Comment: @MSalters: it is true that for most of the assumed changes, there are cases where the API semantics change. It is also true the for the list of changes which are assumed to break the API, you can find versions which do not. The real issue raised by OP, is how can he detect when a change, does not affect the application? –

Comment: It sounds like all the things that documentation cares about.... and doxygen has an XML output mode, that should contain pretty much exactly the information you want to compare.

Comment: Maybe... unit tests?

Comment: @MSalters as said in the original question, I am _not_ interested in ABI breaks (since the API and its implementation is always built and linked statically)

Answer (score 3):

OP is right to think that C++ parsing is probably necessary.  Likely deep reasoning, too.

I think the way to pose the question is,

*for a particular set of uses of an API in an existing application, does changing the API change or break of the application?*

If you don't limit yourself to a specific set of uses, almost any change to an API will change its semantics.  Otherwise, why would you make them (modulo refactoring?).  And if you use the full set of API features in the application, then its semantics must change somehow too.

*With* a specific set of uses, one can arguably determine which properties of the API might affect the specific uses, and determine if in fact they do.  Ultimately you have to parse the original code *accurately* to determine the specific set of uses and the context in which they are used.  You also have to determine the semantic properties on which the existing application depends, *including* the properties provided by the legacy API.  Finally, you need to determine the properties defined by the new API, and verify still support the needs of the application.

In general, you need a theorem prover over the program properties to check this.  And, while theorem proving technology has advanced significantly over the last 50 years, AFAIK said technology isn't strong enough to take generally arbitrary program properties and prove them, let alone overcome the problem of reasoning about arbitrarily complex programs.

Consider:

```
 // my application
 int x=0;
 int y=foo(x); // API ensures that fail...
 if (y>3) then fail(); // shouldn't happen 
 exit();

 // my legacy API
 int foo(int x) { return x+1; }
```

Now imagine the API is changed to:

```
 // my new API
 int foo(int x) { return x+2; }
```

The application still functions correctly.
How about:

```
 // my new API
 int foo(int x) { return TuringMachine(x); }
```

How are we going to prove that TuringMachine(x) produces a value < 3?
If we can't do this for such tiny programs, how are we going to do it
for ones that we write in practice?

Now, you might be able to limit the set of changes you will consider to
simply "syntactic" operations, such as "move method",  "add parameter with initial value", etc.

You'll still need to parse the original program and modified APIs, and check that the syntactic properties imply semantic properties that don't damage the original program.   You'll likely need control and dataflow analysis, alias analysis to worry about pointers, etc, and the tool will at best be able to tell for a limited number of cases when no change has occurred.

I'm sure there are research papers on this topic.  A quick check at scholar.google.com didn't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 3):

See **"Source Compatibility"** tab of the report of the [ABICC](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool. Most of the mentioned API changes and API breaks are detected by this tool.

There are two approaches to use the tool. Original via analysis of header files and a new via analysis of the library debug info ([[1]](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/#ABI_Dumper)). Use the second one. It's more reliable and simple.

You can find some report examples here: http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/

Tutorial: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/ABI_checker#Usage

[image]

[image]